# rickshaw - how do I make charts autoresize to fit container?

Tags: javascript, charts, rickshaw

I am using [rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) to chart some real-time data in my app. The issue I have is that the space I have available to display the charts varies in time - containers get bigger/smaller when certain conditions are met. As a result, I need to resize the charts manually (with extra code).

The other charting library I have used previously (highcharts) by default "resizes to fit its parent" when dimensions are not manually specified.

Is there a way to do something similar in rickshaw? If not, how do I implement something similar myself?